# a EULA or an EULA

Tags: articles, vowels

We use "a" before words that start with a consonant sound and "an" before words that start with a vowel sound. "EULA" seems to start with a [semivowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semivowel) sound.

> An [end-user license agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-user_license_agreement) (EULA, /ˈjuːlə/) is a legal contract entered into between a software developer or vendor and the user of the software, often where the software has been purchased by the user from an intermediary such as a retailer. A EULA specifies in detail the rights and restrictions which apply to the use of the software.

Do we right "a" or "an" before "EULA"?